# How to change how my JSON looks

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have an AJAX call that makes my JSON look this in my JSON file:

```
{
  "main_object": {
    "id": "new",
    "formData": "language=nl_NL&getExerciseTitle=test&question_takeAudio_exerciseWord%5B0%5D=test&Syllablescounter%5B0%5D=test&Syllablescounter%5B1%5D=test"
  }
}
```

But I would like to have it like this (and this was before I changed my AJAX call with: `id: getUrlParameter('id')`:

```
{
  "main_object": {
    "language": "nl_NL",
    "getExerciseTitle": "asd",
    "question_takeAudio_exerciseWord": ["asd"],
    "Syllablescounter": ["ASDasd", ""]
  }
}
```

The only thing I want to add is the `"id": "new"`, but when I do so (with `id: getUrlParameter('id')` it gets the id, but it messes up my code.

This is my AJAX call (my JSON starts looking like the first piece of code when I use this)

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
  $("#my_form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'saveJson.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        id: getUrlParameter('id'),
        formData: $('#my_form').serialize()
      },
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response) {

    });
  });
}
```

How could this be achieved? I know it isn't my `saveJson.php` that's the problem. I know it's my AJAX call since it starts showing like the first JSON piece of code when I add the `id: getUrlParameter('id')`.

edit: Since someone said it could be my php code.. here is my php code:

```
<?php
include_once('database_json.php');
$data = $_POST;
//Setup an empty array.
$errors = array();
if (isset($data)) {
    $newExerciseData['main_object'] = $data;
    $exerciseArray = $data['main_object'];
    $databaseFile = 'json_files/database.json';
    $textContent = file_get_contents($databaseFile);
    $database = json_decode($textContent, true);
    if ($data['id'] === 'new') {
        if (count($database['data']) == 0) {
            $ID = 0;
        } // ending database['data'] count 0.
        else {
            $maxID = max($database['data']);
            $ID = ++$maxID["id"];
         } // ending the max ID else statement.
        $newJsonFile = 'jsonData_' . $ID . '.json';
        $newJsonFilePath = 'json_files/' . $newJsonFile;
        //Create new database exercise_txt
        $newArrayData = array(
        'id' => $ID,
        'exercisetitle' => $data['formData']['getExerciseTitle'],
        'language' => $data['formData']['language'],
        'file' => $newJsonFile
    );
    $database['data'][] = $newArrayData;
    file_put_contents($databaseFile, json_encode($database, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    file_put_contents($newJsonFilePath, json_encode($newExerciseData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
} // } op regel 34 lijkt verdwaald...?
else {
    $index = array_search((int) $_POST['id'], array_column($database['data'], 'id'));
    $correctJsonFile = 'json_files/jsonData_' . $_POST['id'] . '.json';
    $newJsonFile = 'jsonData_' . $_POST['id'] . '.json';
    $newJsonFilePath = 'json_files/' . $newJsonFile;
    //Create new database exercise_txt
    $newArrayData2 = array(
        'id' => (int) $data['id'],
        'exercisetitle' => $data['formData']['getExerciseTitle'],
        'language' => $data['formData']['language'],
        'file' => $newJsonFile
    );
    $database['data'][$index] = $newArrayData2;
    file_put_contents($databaseFile, json_encode($database, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    file_put_contents($newJsonFilePath, json_encode($newExerciseData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
} // closing off the else statement
 echo json_encode($newExerciseData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
} //closing off the if isset.
?>
```

Comment: The answer is in your PHP code, it does something you didn't expect with the passed `id` field.

Comment: would u like to see my PHP code? maybe that will do the work (although the amount of code in the post will be insane much)

Comment: Please don't post tons of code, just the relevant part. What does `getUrlParameter` return? You could try to assign the value to a hidden field in `#my_form`, though this probably should also be handled in PHP code too.

Comment: I tried providing all the code that's relevant, atleast that looked relevant to me. my apologies if it's too much (and most likely code that won't be relevant, i'm no pro on this website, neither as a programmer)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `parse_str($str, $output);` it will help you achieve what you need.
Note that parse_str takes two parameters, the first one is the string (get Parameters), second one is the array to return the result on. you can use the below code

`parse_str($str, $output);
echo json_encode($output);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you process formData parameter. `serialize()` is building url encoded string, however you want key-value pairs. Try this:

```
$("#my_form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myData = {id: getUrlParameter('id')};
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        myData[pair[0]] = pair[1]; 
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: 'saveJson.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: myData,
      dataType: 'json',
   }).done(function(response) {
      window.location = 'index.php';
   });
 });
}
```

Comment: when I do this the functionality of my website drops to 0 haha. I lose my add button and the language selector doesn't work either, still appreciate the effort tho.

Comment: Check your console for errors. btw it is weird that you use ajax and redirect user somewhere else on the same time. Why are you just not submitting the form?

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I heard that one before. That's one I tell myself to take out everytime but forget to do so. edit: So, now my functonality does work (it had an unexpected token), but it doesn't submit anything actually. so that's a bit unfortunate. my console gives no error back